# Build system for an embedded C/C++ project

Tags: c++, c, build, build-process, build-system

I am looking for a high-level build system/tool that can help organise my embedded C project into "modules" and "components". Note that these two terms are highly subjective so my definitions are given below.

- A module is a cohesive collection of c and h files but with only one public h file that is visible to other modules.
- A component (or a layer) on the other hand is a collection of modules (e.g. Application layer, Library layer, Driver layer, RTOS layer etc.).

The build system/tool should -

- Prevent cyclic dependencies between components and modules (cyclic dependencies inside modules is okay)
- prevent access to private barriers of a module. If other modules try to include a header file that is private to a module, the build system must throw an error. However, files within a private barrier must be able to include other files inside that barrier.
- support building and executing of unit tests automatically (fast feedback loop for TDD) on host
- support unit tests to be run on target simulator
- support code static analysis
- support code generation
- support code duplication detection (enforce DRY principle)
- support code beautification
- support generation of unit test code coverage metrics
- support generation of code quality metrics
- be platform-independent

I could write my own build tool and spend a lot of time on it. However, that is not my area of expertise and I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if someone has already created such a tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional way of achieving that would be to place the source code for each module into a separate directory.  Each directory can contain all the source and header files for the module.

The public header for each module can be placed into a separate, common directory of headers.  I'd probably use a symlink from the common directory to the relevant module directory for each header.

The compilation rules simply state that no module may include headers from other modules except for the headers in the common directory.  This achieves the result that no module can include headers from another module - except for the public header (thus enforcing the private barriers).

Preventing cyclic dependencies automatically is not trivial.  The problem is that you can only establish that there is a cyclic dependency by looking at several source files at a time, and the compiler only looks at one at a time.

Consider a pair of modules, ModuleA and ModuleB, and a program, Program1, that uses both modules.

```
base/include
        ModuleA.h
        ModuleB.h
base/ModuleA
        ModuleA.h
        ModuleA1.c
        ModuleA2.c
base/ModuleB
        ModuleB.h
        ModuleB1.c
        ModuleB2.c
base/Program1
        Program1.c
```

When compiling Program1.c, it is perfectly legitimate for it to include both ModuleA.h and ModuleB.h if it makes use of the services of both modules.  So, ModuleA.h cannot complain if ModuleB.h is included in the same translation unit (TU), and neither can ModuleB.h complain if ModuleA.h is included in the same TU.

Let us suppose it is legitimate for ModuleA to use the facilities of ModuleB.  Therefore, when compiling ModuleA1.c or ModuleA2.c, there can be no issue with having both ModuleA.h and ModuleB.h included.

However, to prevent cyclic dependencies, you must be able to prohibit the code in ModuleB1.c and ModuleB2.c from using ModuleA.h.

As far as I can see, the only way to do this is some technique that requires a private header for ModuleB that says "ModuleA is already included" even though it isn't, and this is included before ModuleA.h is ever included.

The skeleton of ModuleA.h will be the standard format (and ModuleB.h will be similar):

```
#ifndef MODULEA_H_INCLUDED
#define MODULEA_H_INCLUDED
...contents of ModuleA.h...
#endif
```

Now, if the code in ModuleB1.c contains:

```
#define MODULEA_H_INCLUDED
#include "ModuleB.h"
...if ModuleA.h is also included, it will declare nothing...
...so anything that depends on its contents will fail to compile...
```

This is far from automatic.

You could do an analysis of the included files, and require that there is a loop-less topological sort of the dependencies.  There used to be a program `tsort` on UNIX systems (and a companion program, `lorder`) which together provided the services needed so that a static (`.a`) library could be created that contained the object files in an order that did not require rescanning of the archive.  The `ranlib` program, and eventually `ar` and `ld` took on the duties of managing the rescanning of a single library, thus making `lorder` in particular redundant.  But `tsort` has more general uses; it is available on some systems (MacOS X, for instance; RHEL 5 Linux too).

So, using the dependency tracking from GCC plus `tsort`, you should be able to check whether there are cycles between modules.  But that would have to be handled with some care.

There may be some IDE or other toolset that handles this stuff automatically.  But normally programmers can be disciplined enough to avoid problems - as long as the requirements and inter-module dependencies are carefully documented.

Comment: Jonathan, what would the tool of choice be to implement your suggested solution? Make, CMake, Rake or something else entirely?

Comment: I don't have strong views on the more modern systems; I've seen CMake extolled, but you could probably use any of them. It might depend in part on which languages your most familiar with. If you use Ruby, then Rake makes sense, for example. I still tend to use plain old Make, but I've been doing that for...rather a long time...so I feel comfortable doing so. It is something of a lowest common denominator solution, with portability issues. I sometimes use Autoconf to deal with the portability issues, but that has its own set complexities (and increases the size of small projects dramatically).

Comment: Fair enough, I've been using Rake but I can't say that I'm particularly fond of it. I basically don't want to have to spend too much time on a build system, when I can be working on the actual project which at the end of the day pays the bills. Are there any off-the-shelf solutions for this at all?

Comment: I take my previous comment back, I've been working on a flexible build framework (using Rake) for C/C++ projects which I'll be open sourcing soon. It implements all of the above features + more.

Answer (score 2):

For a general solution, I'd fully recommend to go with Jonathan Leffler's solution. However, if you absolutely need an automated test whether your modules are self-contained and isolated, you might give Debian's build system a try.

Package each module into a Debian package (which is done very quickly when it's already autoconf'd), declare Build-Depends properly and build the packages inside a pbuilder environment. This ensures that only public headers of each module are available (because only those are in the .deb packages that are installed by pbuilder to build the other packages) and there are excellent tools to look at Debian package trees and make sure they are cycle-free.

However, this is probably over-kill. Just stating it for completeness and the case you definitely need an automated solution.